# I can not connect to SMB shares after upgrading macOS from Mojave to Catalina

Tags: macos, network, smb, catalina

Before I upgraded, I used <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> to connect an SMB share. I had upgraded macOS from Mojave to Catalina yesterday. When I use <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> to connect that SMB share, it doesn’t work.

Does the new macOS disable SMB? Help me please, it has decreasesed my work efficiency.

Comment: What is the kind of SMB share? A NAS, a Windows server, a Mac server? Please elaborate a bit (NAS model, Windows version etc.).

Comment: Does any of the info [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/362739/168832) help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it in a strange way, 
As we are all aware Mac user has actually 2 names: one is the username (the profile name if i may) and the Display name.

Prior to Catalina , when authenticating with an SMB share from a Windows computer , I was using the display name (although it is a full name with a space - strange for the traditional windows user...) and everything was cool.

In Catalina , I found out I can only use the username, windows cannot authenticate with the display name.

of course , before I got to this point I have checked/enabled SMBv2, created the NetBios file in the MAC and all the other hints I could find, which obviously did not do the trick for me.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

SMB is not disabled, but netbios name resolution is. See this answer to test if you just need to set up DNS or reactivate netbios.

- [What causes some Network Drives using SMB no longer connect to macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362739/what-causes-some-network-drives-using-smb-no-longer-connect-to-macos-catalina)

You can always connect by IP address to test if it’s name resolution before changing your preference files or altering the system configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling connecting to my QNAP NAS via SMB for a while now too (from Catalina 10.15).  First I switched to afp protocol which seemed to work better, but I hate workarounds instead of solutions. In the end, this seems to have fixed the problem for me: delete the Finder preferences.

Use the Finder menu to go to a folder (<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>) and copy this path in: `~/Library/Preferences/`
Then locate the file: `com.apple.finder.plist` and Delete it (move to Trashcan).

I always empty my trash too, not sure if that's important here.

SMB is lightning fast now, faster than it's ever been.