# Catalina No Longer Connects To Windows 10 NAS

Tags: windows, catalina, smb, nas

Everything was fine under Mojave, but when I upgraded to Catalina my Mac can no longer connect to my Windows 10 NAS. It's not the NAS because I have other Windows 10 and even Raspberry Pis connecting to it. I can see all of my computers on the network through Finder, I just cannot connect to any of them.

I started with this post to create an nsmb.conf file because my system did not have one. Not sure if it did under Mojave because I didn't have a problem, so I am assuming it did not have one.

https://macintoshhowto.com/advanced/how-to-speed-up-network-drives-on-os-x-mojave.html

When that did not work, I reviewed the following post and it still did not resolve my problem.

[What causes some Network Drives using SMB no longer connect to macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362739/what-causes-some-network-drives-using-smb-no-longer-connect-to-macos-catalina)

It's frustrating that something that should be so very easy has become so very difficult.

Comment: Seriously, i can't connect to mine either. It's beyond frustrating.