# SMB Port 139 not enabled on Mac OS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: catalina, sharing, smb, scanning

I'm trying to share a folder on my local network in order to use a scanner that can upload files over SMB protocol towards a Mac Catalina 10.15.

My Mac is on my local network with IP address 192.168.1.54

The scanner is an old scanner, it can't use the 445 port, but it works perfectly with Windows 10 on port 139.

I've tried:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P | grep :139
```

It returns nothing, so I think that the 139 port is not listening.

I've tried to open a Windows VM on the Mac, and:

```
telnet 192.168.1.54 445
```

it connects, but:

```
telnet 192.168.1.54 139
```

don't work.

I've tried also the suggestion reported here [What causes some Network Drives using SMB no longer connect to macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362739/what-causes-some-network-drives-using-smb-no-longer-connect-to-macos-catalina), but even adding the file `/etc/nsmb.conf` the port 139 is still not working.

I also made a system reboot, but nothing has changed.

Any idea?

Thanks