# Unable to connect to SMB share after reboot

Tags: smb

I just got a new iMac (M1 & Big Sur). I have a shared hard drive on my router that I've maintained as a shared network drive on the Windows machine I'm replacing. This machine is still connected to the shared drive, and can browse & edit its contents, etc.

I got my iMac connected to the share on the first try, using `smb://192.168.1.1/ShareName`. I know the IP address is correct - it's the IP for the router, and it's what works for the mapped drive on the Windows machine.

After I rebooted, I can't connect to the shared drive. It shows the *'There was a problem connecting to the server "192.168.1.1".* message.

This is a pain to diagnose, especially with a brand new computer (and I'm switching back to Mac after 5y on Windows). I can see the server in my Recent Items under the Apple menu. I just don't get it what the change would have been after reboot; all I've been doing is installing programs and copying files.

I did see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362739/what-causes-some-network-drives-using-smb-no-longer-connect-to-macos-catalina) and tried the enable Netbios suggestion, which didn't work either before or after another restart.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Router model? Format of hard drive?

Comment: Go figure - it's working today.

Router is whatever comes with Spectrum (RAC2V1S). The shared drive is shockingly reliable, way more than my previous router (which was a Netgear R7000). Hard drive is formatted as NTFS.